# adding external nfc adapter in android device

Tags: android, android-ndk, nfc

i have external felica NFC device adapter now i want to connect that device using usb adapter to android if it is possible to get that device output to my device. my device won't support NFC so that i buy external device.guide me how to make that device is detect it in my android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device must support USB host, so it must run 3.1 or later. You then need to basically write your own driver for the NFC adapter in your app.

Comment: thank you..kindly tell me how to write driver program can you post some examples or reference URLs...